# can i insert different objects in a httppost in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm new with asp.net and mvc, i'm trying to send a int, a list of int from a different object, and other list of ints from a other object, with a form.

my view for insert the int is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Guardar", "pedidoEmp"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
    <center>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.empleadoId)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.empleadoId, new SelectList(Model.verEmp, "empleadoId", "Nombre"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.empleadoId)
        </div>
    </center>
```

and the list are

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.verMenu.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(menuId => Model.verMenu[i].MenuId)

                @Html.DisplayFor(sopa => Model.verMenu[i].Sopa)
            </td>
```

.
.
.

```
  <div class="form-group">

                        @for (var o = 0; o < Model.opMenuVer.Count; o++)
                        {
                            if (Model.opMenuVer[o].MenuId == Model.verMenu[i].MenuId)
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBox("OpcionId", new { value = Model.opMenuVer[o].OpcionId })
                                @Html.Label(Model.opMenuVer[o].Nombre)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.opMenuVer[o].OpcionId)
                            }
                        }

                    </div>
</td>
        </tr>
    }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    }
```

in my controller the httppost i try to do something like this

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Guardar(int idEmp, List<int> menusId, List<int> opsId)
        {
            List<PedidoXEmpleados> pedido = new List<PedidoXEmpleados>(); 
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("agregarMenu");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < menusId.Count; i++)
            {
                pedido[i].estadoPedido = true;
                pedido[i].EmpleadoId = idEmp;
                pedido[i].MenuId = menusId[i];
                pedido[i].OpcionId = opsId[i];
                _conBd.PedidoXEmpleados.Add(pedido[i]);
            }

            _conBd.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

thank you very much, i try to search for other parts and i didn't find something that works, when i try the project show me this, "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idEmp' of non-nullable type".

Comment: Because your not sending a value for `idEmp` in the request. (but you do have one named `empleadoId`)

Comment: thank you so much stephen, i change it and works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all names of your parameters should match the names of your properties and do these changes to your code

```
@Html.DropDownList("idEmp", new SelectList(Model.verEmp, "empleadoId", "Nombre"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.CheckBox("opsId", new { value = Model.opMenuVer[o].OpcionId })

@Html.Hidden("menusId",Model.verMenu[i].MenuId)
```

Comment: thanks so much, i make that changes in the checkbox and hidden and works. thaaanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is create a viewModel with properties for the int and the 2 lists. Then use this viewModel as the model of the view and pass the values to the models in contoller. This class shouldn't have an Id property or DbSet.